# python try/exception help

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to support repetition where the user inputs a filename, then inputs two integers. So if an exception is thrown, I want the user to be prompted with input again.

My problem is if a valid file is entered but an invalid integer is entered it will ask for the file again instead of just the integer.  How can I fix the code so it will ask for the integer again.

Here is what I have:

```
while True:
    try:
        f = raw_input("Enter name of file: ")
        inFile = open(f)
        # more code
    except IOError:
        print ("The file does not exist. Try Again.")        
    else:    
        try:
            integer = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
            integer2 = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
            # more code
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print ("Not an integer. Try Again.")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try use multiple `while` loops:

```
while True:
    fileName = raw_input("Enter name of file: ")
    try:
        # more code here to detect or open the file
        break
    except Exception:  # can be IOError or something else
        print ("error msg")

while True:
    try:
        integer = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
        integer2 = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
        break
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("error msg")

# more code
```

Comment: Thanks, multiple loops works!!! But when in the second loop say the first integer entered is valid but the second integer entered is invalid.  It will then prompt you to reenter both integers again. Is it possible to just prompt that last integer again?

Comment: @michael, you can break the 2nd loop into two loops, one for each ``raw_input``

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        a = int(raw_input('a: '))
        b = int(raw_input('b: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Numbers idiot"
#more code here
```

This code will jump to the except block on a or b and carry on with more code if the numbers work.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def ask(question, func, exceptions):
...     while True:
...         try:
...             return func(raw_input(question))
...         except exceptions, error:
...             pass
... 
>>> x = ask("integer?", int, ValueError)
integer?o
integer?l
integer?42
>>> x
42
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on an answer above regarding using multiple while loops and the related question about handling additional data verification without having to loop over already verified data, the following looks crufty but it gives you the granular inspection you're looking to achieve:

```
while True:
    fileName = raw_input("Enter name of file: ")
    try:
        # more code here to detect or open the file
        break
    except Exception:
        print ("The file does not exist. Try Again.")

while True:
    try:
        integer = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
        break
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("Not an integer. Try Again.")

while True:
    try:
        integer2 = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
        break
    except(TypeError, ValueError):
        print ("Not an integer. Try Again.")
```